# How to check that particular string format is only allowed in UITextField?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uitextfield

I want to check that only alphabetic,numeric and some special character is allowed in my textfield.Only %&@-_. this special character is allowed in textfield , other special character is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

in the delegate, and check that all characters in `string` are of the kind that you allow.

One very simple way of checking characters for membership in a set is by using [`NSCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nscharacterset_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.